# File write buffering in Shell script

Tags: linux, shell

I have a start up shell script which reads a value from the file, increments it by 1 and writes it back. After that I do power-cycling of the system(switch off and switch on the power supply). I am trying to record the number of reboots using this way. But I find that the file counter always remains at 1. If I do the reboot using the reboot command, the counter in the file increments properly. Is this because the file write is buffered and delayed by the kernel. Is there a way to force it to write immediately?

The rc.user file is as follows:

```
cd /root
bash bootcounter.sh
sleep 1
```

bootcounter.sh is as follows

```
rebootcount=$(<bootcount)
rebootcount=$(($rebootcount+1))
echo $rebootcount >bootcount
```

Thanks...

Comment: In Bash and some other shells, you can do `((rebootcount++))` or `((rebootcount += 1))`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want the sync command.  This should flush all the file systems.

```
count=$( cat bootcount )
echo $( expr $count + 1 ) > bootcount
sync
```

You should probably use a full path to bootcount, though.

Answer (score 1):

There's no simple and unified answer for syncing file operation in filesystem - it's all very filesystem-dependent. For example, in fact, there could be no force writing, as there could be no writing at all - if we're talking about purely virtual system - or there could be multiple layers of writing, if we're talking about some network-exported file system.

There are a few things you can try, but generally, "your mileage may vary":

- There's one common way to make file system permanent state consistent - `umount` it. Most Linux distros unmount all filesystems during shutdown process and it ensures their clean and fully-dumped-to-hardware-drive state.
- If umounting is not an option, may be you can at least remount it as read-only - it effectively does the same shutdown procedures as unmounting, but leaves filesystem accessible - something like `mount -o remount,ro /YOUR-FILE-SYSTEM`
- If these are not possible, you can try running `sync`, but it has it's own glitches:

  - `sync` call is just an advice for filesystem, not a strict command
  - `sync` call may start syncing, but syncing itself takes some time; there's no way to know when syncing is finished
  - sometimes adding stuff like `sleep 5` to sleep for 5 seconds to let the disc do the syncing helps
  - sometimes people using workaround like `sync; sync; sync` which is kind of reported to help in some mysterious way too
- You might want to also try emptying the cache: `echo 3 >/proc/sys/vm/drop_caches` - it will also force dumping of cache that should be written, but it also takes time and there's no way to know if it's finished. Sometimes combinations of all methods work, i.e:

```
sync; sync; sync
sleep 5
echo 3 >/proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. The sync option works for now!

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
rebootcount=`expr $rebootcount + 1`
echo $rebootcount >bootcount
```

or more simply:

```
echo `expr $rebootcount + 1` >bootcount
```

Comment: no this does not help. The counter doe increment properly when I reboot using reboot command(soft reboot). But switching off and on the power supply confuses it.

Answer (score 0):

This information is already being tracked! Use the following:

```
last reboot
```

Which lists all of the previous system boots since the file `/var/log/wtmp` was created. In addition, it tells you how long the server was up, at what time it went up and went down.

Looks like this:

```
reboot   system boot  2.6.35.10-74.fc1 Sun Jan  9 11:19 - 11:48  (00:28)    
reboot   system boot  2.6.35.10-74.fc1 Sun Jan  9 05:27 - 05:45  (00:17)    
reboot   system boot  2.6.35.10-74.fc1 Sat Jan  8 05:30 - 09:43  (04:12)
```

Just saying.